# In 8 ball, can I call the same pocket with my opponent for the last ball?

Tags: rules, pool

Assume that there are two balls left on the table (black and white). Can I call the pocket which is called by my opponent in his turn? We do not allow it, but we are not sure where the rule is coming from. I could not find such a thing on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [U.S. 8-Ball Rules](http://upatour.com/official-billiard-rules/u-s-8-ball-rules/) do not contain any such rule; in theory you would have to read the entire rulebook to prove the negative, but Rule 6 "Call Pocket" is probably a good section to quote if you want to.

Obviously, if you're playing under a different set of rules, then refer to the rule book for whichever rules you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your oppositions' choice of pocket has no impact on yours, in any 8-ball rules.

Comment: A reference would go a long way in making your answer more legitimate.